# Get the folder of a file.

Tags: c#

I have a folder fuill of images and have the image name and the full file path stored in an array in my program. Is it possible to get just the folder and the filename from the filepath.

So If I have a filepath of

```
C:\Users\Ryan\Documents\myImage.jpg
```

I need to get

```
Documents\myImage.jpg
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use this code:

```
FileInfo f = new FileInfo(@"C:\Users\Ryan\Documents\myImage.jpg");
string result = Path.Combine(f.Directory.Name, f.Name);
```

Comment: @farhan tnx  already delted my comment when I saw you fix it. didnt want to clutter with comments ^^

Comment: @TimSchmelter In fact, you need to use `Path.Combine`, because if you are at the root, e.g. `C:\file.txt` then the `Directory.Name` returns `C:\ `.

Comment: @TimSchmelter But won't it will also help others discover that the second approach can yield wrong paths?

Comment: @Anyways, I removed it.

Answer (score 2):

The [`Path`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path(v=vs.110).aspx) class has methods to work with file names:

```
var path = @"C:\Users\Ryan\Documents\myImage.jpg";
var fileName = Path.GetFileName(path);
var directoryName = Path.GetDirectoryName(path);
var lastDirectoryName = Path.GetFileName(directoryName);
var result = Path.Combine(lastDirectoryName, fileName);
```

Comment: Works also but the usage of `Path.GetFileName` for a directory is not as readable as the `FileInfo.Directory.Name` approach. +1

Answer (score 0):

```
var pathParts = filepath.split('\\');
var lastPath = pathParts[pathParts - 2] + @"\" + pathParts[pathParts - 1];
```

Answer (score 0):

This is just playing with the string but it does the job

```
    string path = "C:\Users\Ryan\Documents\myImage.jpg";
    string[] temp = path.Split('\');
    string folder = temp[temp.Length - 2] + @"\" + temp[temp.Length - 1];
```